# Bind Command To ContextMenu Item

Tags: c#, wpf

I am getting this error/warning:

```
System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with reference 'ElementName=DrivesListView'
```

When I press 'Refresh', the command does not fire. I am guessing since it is a ContextMenu, I need to somehow access the parent control in the binding path and then I can use `MouseDownCommand`.

`MouseDownCommand` is located in my tab viewmodel, `TabItemViewModel`. My `MainWindowViewModel` contains a list of `TabItemViewModel`s, and that is the source of the `TabControl`'s items.

## **What I've tried:**

### **1)**

I've tried setting the ContextMenu Opened event to set the DataContext manually like this to see if it would fix the DataContext somehow:

```
private void ContextMenu_Opened(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ContextMenu menu = sender as ContextMenu;
    ListView listView = menu.PlacementTarget as ListView;
    Grid grid = listView.Parent as Grid;
    TabControl tabControl = grid.Parent as TabControl;
    menu.DataContext = (TabItemViewModel)tabControl.SelectedItem;
}
```

The problem with this is the fact that I cannot seem to get the `tabControl` from the `grid`. Doing `.Parent` just returns `null` for some unknown reason.

### 2)

I also tried setting the `Tag` of the control, which did not work either:

```
<ListView Grid.Row="1" Name="DrivesListView" ItemsSource="{Binding Drives}"
                                  Tag="{Binding DataContext,RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,AncestorType=Window}}">>
    <ListView.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu>
            <MenuItem Header="Refresh">
                <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                    <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseDown">
                        <i:InvokeCommandAction 
                                                    Command="{Binding Path=PlacementTarget.Tag.MouseDownCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=ContextMenu}}" 
                                                       CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=DrivesListView}"/>
                    </i:EventTrigger>
                </i:Interaction.Triggers>
            </MenuItem>
        </ContextMenu>
    </ListView.ContextMenu>
    <ListView.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListView}" BasedOn="{StaticResource MahApps.Styles.ListView}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding DrivesListViewEnabled}" Value="true">
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding DrivesListViewEnabled}" Value="false">
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ListView.Style>
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseDoubleClick">
            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding Path=MouseDoubleClickCommand}" 
                                                       CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=DrivesListView}"/>
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn x:Name="NameHeader" Header="Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}"/>
            <GridViewColumn x:Name="TypeHeader" Header="Type" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Type}"/>
            <GridViewColumn x:Name="TotalSizeHeader" Header="Total Size" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding TotalSize}"/>
            <GridViewColumn x:Name="FreeSpaceHeader" Header="Free Space" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding FreeSpace}"/>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

Here is my XAML

```
<UserControl x:Class="FileExplorerModuleServer.Views.FileBrowserTabView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity" xmlns:mah="http://metro.mahapps.com/winfx/xaml/controls"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <!--ItemsSource is bound to the 'Tabs' property on the view-
                        model, while DisplayMemeberPath tells TabControl 
                        which property on each tab has the tab's name -->
        <TabControl Name="SubTabControl" Grid.Row="1" 
                    ItemsSource="{Binding Tabs}" 
                    DisplayMemberPath="Header" SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedIndex}">
            <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
                    <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding Path=TabChangedCommand}" 
                                                       CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=SubTabControl}"/>
                </i:EventTrigger>
            </i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                        <TextBox Grid.Row="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="300" Text="{Binding Path}">

                        </TextBox>

                        <mah:ProgressRing Grid.Row="1" Height="1">
                            <mah:ProgressRing.Style>
                                <Style TargetType="{x:Type mah:ProgressRing}">
                                    <Style.Triggers>
                                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsLoading}" Value="true">
                                            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                                        </DataTrigger>
                                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsLoading}" Value="false">
                                            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden" />
                                        </DataTrigger>
                                    </Style.Triggers>
                                </Style>
                            </mah:ProgressRing.Style>
                        </mah:ProgressRing>

                        <ListView Grid.Row="1" Name="DrivesListView" ItemsSource="{Binding Drives}">
                            <ListView.ContextMenu>
                                <ContextMenu Opened="ContextMenu_Opened">
                                    <MenuItem Header="Refresh">
                                        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                                            <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseDown">
                                                <i:InvokeCommandAction 
                                                    Command="{Binding Path=MouseDownCommand}" 
                                                       CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=DrivesListView}"/>
                                            </i:EventTrigger>
                                        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                                    </MenuItem>
                                </ContextMenu>
                            </ListView.ContextMenu>
                            <ListView.Style>
                                <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListView}" BasedOn="{StaticResource MahApps.Styles.ListView}">
                                    <Style.Triggers>
                                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding DrivesListViewEnabled}" Value="true">
                                            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                                        </DataTrigger>
                                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding DrivesListViewEnabled}" Value="false">
                                            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden" />
                                        </DataTrigger>
                                    </Style.Triggers>
                                </Style>
                            </ListView.Style>
                            <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                                <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseDoubleClick">
                                    <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding Path=MouseDoubleClickCommand}" 
                                                       CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=DrivesListView}"/>
                                </i:EventTrigger>
                            </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                            <ListView.View>
                                <GridView>
                                    <GridViewColumn x:Name="NameHeader" Header="Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}"/>
                                    <GridViewColumn x:Name="TypeHeader" Header="Type" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Type}"/>
                                    <GridViewColumn x:Name="TotalSizeHeader" Header="Total Size" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding TotalSize}"/>
                                    <GridViewColumn x:Name="FreeSpaceHeader" Header="Free Space" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding FreeSpace}"/>
                                </GridView>
                            </ListView.View>
                        </ListView>
```

Here is the ViewModel.cs

```
public ICommand MouseDownCommand
    => new RelayCommand<object>(e => MouseDown(e));

private void MouseDown(object commandParameter)
{

}
```

Comment: So `DataContext` of the ListView is bound to `TabItemViewModel` and `Drives` is one of its properties? Then you want to set that ListView into CommandParameter?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: The trigger on the `SelectionChanged` event is a mess, just use a binding: `SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedTab, Mode=OneWayToSource}"` ; then in the VM, add a `SelectedTab` property of the type of the objects in the `Tabs` collection. Then move the code of `TabChangedCommand` to the setter of the `SelectedTab` property.

Comment: The `ListView.Style` is also a mess, just use a [BooleanToVisibilityConverter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3128023): `Visibility="{Binding DrivesListViewEnabled, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"`

Comment: I'll look into those two changes you suggested. The last one however requires the addition of a custom class if I'm not mistaken, and that is rather annoying and what I was trying to avoid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/controls/contextmenu?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8), *[the] menu [...] is specific to the context of the control*.
In other words, the `ContextMenu` has the same data context as  it's parent control (here the `ListView`).
To follow the MVVM pattern, you then only need to add a `ICommand` in the data context of the `ListView` and bind it to the `MenuItem.Command` property.

The View:

```xml
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Drives}">
    <ListView.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu>
            <MenuItem Header="Refresh" Command="{Binding RefreshCommand}" />
        </ContextMenu>
    </ListView.ContextMenu>
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}"/>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Type" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Type}"/>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Total Size" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding TotalSize}"/>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Free Space" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding FreeSpace, StringFormat='{}{0:0.00}'}"/>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

The ViewModel:

```csharp
public class ViewModel
{
    public ViewModel()
    {
        RefreshCommand = new ActionCommand(Refresh);
    }

    public IReadOnlyList<DriveViewModel> Drives { get; }

    public ICommand RefreshCommand { get; }

    private void Refresh()
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Working demo available [here](https://github.com/Orace/SO/tree/main/SO_72267688).

Comment: If you really need to run the command on the `MouseDown` event and not just when the menu item is clicked / selected (via keyboard), then the answer is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17835205). But this is not a standard behavior and I don't see why one may want to do it this way.

Comment: I fixed it by changing it to Click. MouseDown appears to not function at all for ContextMenu. Not sure why it's even available as an event.

Comment: @MemeMachine `I fixed it by changing it to Click` to handle a Click event, you don't need a `Interaction.Triggers\EventTrigger\InvokeCommandAction` subtree, just use the `Command` and `CommandParameter` attribute of the menu item. And again, I don't believe you need to pass a parameter, so `CommandParameter` is useless in your case.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, `MouseDown` event doesn't seem to work well in the case of `MenuItem`. So, you need to use `PreviewMouseDown` or probaby `Click` event instread. Also, you cannot use ElementName for referring elements outside of `ContextMenu`.

Then, assuming `DataContext` of the `ListView` is implicitly bound to `TabItemViewModel` and you want to specify that `ListView` as `CommandParameter`, it could be modified as follows:

```xml
<MenuItem Header="Refresh">
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
            <i:InvokeCommandAction
                Command="{Binding PlacementTarget.DataContext.MouseDownCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ContextMenu}}}"
                CommandParameter="{Binding PlacementTarget, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ContextMenu}}}"/>
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</MenuItem>
```

Comment: Why do you bother to use a trigger when a `Command` property is available ?

Comment: You are right. In the case of "Click" event, it is not necessary to use `InvokeCommandAction`.

Comment: Can you explain how your CommandParameter works? I used a mixture of both of your answers since @Orace forgot to add the CommandParameter to his, and the one from your answer works great. I wish I could select both of yours as the right answer. Thanks!

Comment: The binding for CommandParameter refers to `ContextMenu.PlacementTarget` property and this property provides the element to which the ContextMenu is attached. In this case, it is the ListView. That's it.

Comment: @MemeMachine why do you need a command parameter? To pass a `ListView` ? so you pass a view object to the view model ?! What will you do with that?

Comment: @emoacht I modified your code today to try and make it so a particular MenuItem will only be available when a ListView item is selected. I am getting "Propery 'Path' is set multiple times". Any idea why? Thank you so much for your help https://pastebin.com/RVGk8UwF

Comment: @MemeMachine You set path two times by `PlacementTarget` and `Path=SelectedItem`.  You can change it to `Path=PlacementTarget.SelectedItem`. I don't know whether it works in your particular case though.

Comment: @emoacht Hm, doesn't seem to work - https://pastebin.com/GE4mE852 - does not appear to check if no item is selected (i.e if i select an empty space in the ListView, 'Rename' menu option still appears. If you don't see anything wrong, I will open another question